# react undux testing (mock) with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Please how can I test **.subscribe** as a chained function to **.on** :

in component :

```
store.on('event').subscribe(val => {
    ...
});
```

test:

```
const mockStore = {
    get: () => null,
    set: () => {},
    on: () => jest.fn(),
};

describe('TEST', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<component store={mockStore} />);
    
    it('Should render', () => {
          expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

get and set works,

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but the following should work I think:

Instead of mocking `on` function with `jest.fn()`, you can return an object containing `subscribe` function on it. Like this:

```
const mockStore = {
    get: () => null,
    set: () => {},
    on: (eventStr) => ({
        subscribe: jest.fn(),
    }),
};
const subscribeSpy = jest.spyOn(mockStore.on('event'), 'subscribe');
```

and then expect it to be called when needed,

```
expect(subscribeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```